# Show all products that belong_to category id in application.html navigation Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to dynamically link_to all product names that belong to a category_id in my application.html navigation.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :set_products
    before_action :set_categories
    rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to main_app.root_url, alert: exception.message
end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_products
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def set_categories
    @categories = Category.all 
  end
end
```

product.rb

```
belongs_to :category
```

category.rb

```
has_many :products
```

application.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
 <%= link_to product.name, product, class: "link-item nav-link roll", src: url_for(product.header_image) %>
<% end %>
```

I can show all the product names or all the category names but not the names of each product of a specific category separately in the navigation.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your `category.products`. `category.products` will return to you all the Product models that belong to a certain `category`.

Try:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
 <% category.products.each do |product| %>
   <%= link_to product.name, product, class: "link-item nav-link roll", src: url_for(product.header_image) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Check the Active Record Associations [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) to see all the association related methods you can use in cases of `has_many` and `belongs_to` association reference.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your solution. I've tried it and I'm getting the same result as before. My problem is not showing the product names, it's that I only want to show the products that belong to a specific category. For example, I want to show all the product names that belong to the tables category under one dropdown link and all the product names that belong to the chairs category in another.

Comment: Hi Paul, how do you specify that category? Via a name param in your controller you can do: `@category = Category.find_by_name(params[:name])` and then do `@category.products` to iterate over products of the specified category.

Comment: I specify the category by name which is given an id. I would like to call that id and display the products associated. The change to the controll you mentioned above, does that refer to my application_controller.rb?                                      My schema below                                            
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

Comment: Yes, try that inside `application_controller.rb`, since that seems to be the only controller you're using.

Comment: That doesn't seem to effect it unfortunately. I am still getting all the products from my product table and not all the products that belong to the Tables category (category_id 1) from the category table.